# Please always make sure to reset to user's options()

Tags: r, github, devtools, cran

this is CRAN feedback for package release.

I tried to summary the question on `r-package-devel`. However, I do not quite understand the problem and wish to figure out what this problem means.

Anyone know what this mean by ** reset to user's options()**? Which of my part cause this problem?

**feedback**

Please always make sure to reset to user's options(), working directory or par() after you changed it in examples and vignettes and demos.
e.g.:
old <- options(digits = 3)
...
options(old)
e.g. vignette.

**My vignette code**

````
---
title: "Introduction to package"
author: "Bo"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Introduction to package}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

```{r initial, echo = FALSE, cache = FALSE, results = 'hide'}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(
  warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, echo = TRUE,
  fig.width = 7, fig.height = 6, fig.align = 'centre',
  comment = "#>"
)
options(tibble.print_min = 5)
```

```{r, message=FALSE, include = FALSE}
library(forecast)
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```r
options(tibble.print_min = 5)
```

Sets a user-level option. This means that when a user runs any other code after running your snippet, their `tibble.print_min` value may be different from the one they may have set previously and which they may prefer or even rely on for certain outputs. This is considered bad practice, and if you need to alter user-level options, they should be reset after you have changed them. The pattern should therefore be something like:

```r
original <- options("tibble.print_min")
options(tibble.print_min = 5)

# <---- Do stuff with changed option, e.g. print some tibbles ----> 

options(tibble.print_min = original)
```

Comment: I understand. Can I just copy what you written to fix this problem?

Comment: I think so @BocongZhao - that's what the feedback suggests.

Comment: @BocongZhao Simpler: `original <- options(tibble.print_min = 5)`, since function `options` returns the current settings. Then, when done, `options(original)` resets all modified options to the original values.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Also as the feedback suggest, I checked other file, there is no option() but pars() appears a lot. E.g. ```fitness_ts <- function(pars, features, seasonal, n = 120, freq = 12, target, nComp, selected.features) {pars <- pars2list(pars, seasonal, nComp)``` However, it is not par() as suggest in feedback, I wonder if I still need any change for that?